# Open IE and inject variable values (e.g. ScriptEngineMinorVersion)

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript, internet-explorer-9

I would like to make a script that opens a script and injects values.

I have basic part. (example)

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Return = WshShell.Run("iexplore.exe google.com", 1)
```

But I would also like to overwrite some variable values.  This page I am working with has some JavaScript validate that I want to override with my own values.

Example: `ScriptEngineMinorVersion`

This is the main function I want bypass, newer versions of IE fail this test because the bit that checks ScriptEngineMinorVersion is poorly written and the vendor does not support this product any more.

```
function IsBrowserVersionAcceptable()
{
    // Browser detection
    var browser = GetCurrentBrowserVersion();

        // See if the browser is allowed/tested
    if (browser.IsTested())
    {
        AddTestResultRow('BrowserVersion',
                         'OK',
                         'Browser type/version', // TRANS: msgBrowserTypeVersion
                         browser.GetShortDescription(),
                         '');
    }
    else if (browser.IsAllowed())
    {
        AddTestResultRow('BrowserVersion',
                         'Warning',
                         'Browser type/version', // TRANS: msgBrowserTypeVersion
                         browser.GetShortDescription(),
                         // TRANS: msgBrowserTypeVersionNotTested
                         'Using this webpage with your browser is not tested. Webpage client will start, but may not be 100% functional. No warranty is given from this point on.');
        AddWarning(new CWarning('browserversion', browser.GetID()));
    }
    else
    {
        // TRANS: use original message...
        // alert(MsgFormat(localedb.FindString('msgBrowserTooOld').strText, GetTestedBrowserVersions(), browserversion.GetDescription()));
        AddTestResultRow('BrowserVersion',
                         'Error',
                         'Browser type/version', // TRANS: msgBrowserTypeVersion
                         browser.GetShortDescription(),
                         // TRANS: msgBrowserTypeVersionNotAllowed
                         'Webpage does not support the use of the browser you are using at this moment.<br>' +
                         '<small>(User Agent = ' + new String(navigator.userAgent) + ')</small>');
        // Get out, maybe tell the user we will not go on...
        // TRANS: msgErrorCannotGoOn
        ShowStopMessage('There is an error, Webpage cannot go on.');
        return false;
    }

    // Check Script engine version
    if("undefined" == typeof ScriptEngine)
    {
        AddTestResultRow('ScriptEngine',
                         'Error',
                         'Script Engine', // TRANS: msgScriptEngine
                         '-',
                         // TRANS: msgScriptEngineNotAvailable
                         'You do not have a MS Script Engine. This means your browser is not IE or you do not have the Script Engine installed on your system. The Script Engine is needed for this webpage to function correctly.');
        // TRANS: msgErrorCannotGoOn
        ShowStopMessage('There is an error, webpage cannot go on.');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        strScriptEngineVer = ScriptEngineMajorVersion() + '.' + ScriptEngineMinorVersion();
        if (ScriptEngineMajorVersion() == 9.0 ||
            ScriptEngineMinorVersion() == 9.0) 
        {
            AddTestResultRow('ScriptEngine',
                             'OK',
                             'Script Engine', // TRANS: msgScriptEngine
                             strScriptEngineVer,
                             '');                   
        }
        else
        {
        if (ScriptEngineMajorVersion() < 5 ||
            ScriptEngineMinorVersion() < 5)
        {
            AddTestResultRow('ScriptEngine',
                             'Error',
                             'Script Engine', // TRANS: msgScriptEngine
                             strScriptEngineVer,
                             // TRANS: msgScriptEngineWrongVersion
                             'Your version of MS Script Engine is not sufficient, webpage will not function correctly.');
            // TRANS: msgErrorCannotGoOn
            ShowStopMessage('There is an error, webpage cannot go on.');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            AddTestResultRow('ScriptEngine',
                             'OK',
                             'Script Engine', // TRANS: msgScriptEngine
                             strScriptEngineVer,
                             '');
        }
}
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to override the [builtin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7z0ys3a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzaz8hhz%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) by re-implementing it in either VBScript:

```vb
Function ScriptEngineMinorVersion
  ScriptEngineMinorVersion = 42
End Function
```

or JavaScript:

```js
function ScriptEngineMinorVersion() {
  return 42;
}
```

However, the way you start Internet Explorer doesn't give you access to the instance. You could attach to the already running instance:

```vb
Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
For Each wnd In sh.Windows
  If InStr(1, wnd.FullName, "iexplore.exe", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Set ie = wnd
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

or (better yet) spawn the instance like this:

```vb
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "http://www.google.com"

While ie.ReadyState <> 4 : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend
```

But even then I'm not sure if the function redefinition will actually help, because the script code of the web page is running in a different engine, so you'd need to inject the function into the web page, and you need to do it before it's rendered by the browser. The injection could be done like this:

```vb
Set script = ie.document.createElement("script")
script.type = "text/vbscript"
script.text = "Function ScriptEngineMinorVersion : " & _
              "ScriptEngineMinorVersion = 42 : " & _
              "End Function"
ie.document.head.appendChild(script)
```

but I'm not aware of a way to trigger a re-evaluation of the page content (so that the code in the page is re-run) without actually reloading it (which would undo the injection).

Comment: perhaps it maybe easier to have the function IsBrowserVersionAcceptable inject as always true.  The only down side I would see is that the page only works with IE,  but since the vbscript will for the page to open in IE it shouldn't be a problem.